# Count strings with a certain condition

Tags: r

I have the following dataset

```
 #mydata
 Factors    Transactions
  a,c             2
  b               0
  c               0
  d,a             0
  a               1
  a               0 
  b               1
```

I'd like to count those factors who had transactions.For example, we had two times "a" with transaction. I can write a code to give me my desirable outcome for each variable separately. The following is for "a".

```
 nrow (subset (mydata,mydata$Transaction > 0 & length(mydata[grep("a", mydata$Factors),] )> 0))
```

But I have too much variables and do not want to repeat a code for all of them. I would think there should be a way to write a code to give me the results for all of the variables. I wish to have the following out put:

```
#Output
a    2
b    1
c    1
d    0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With tidyverse packages, assuming your data is strings/factors and numbers,

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

       # separate factors with two elements
df %>% separate_rows(Factors) %>% 
  # set grouping for aggregation
  group_by(Factors) %>% 
  # for each group, count how many transactions are greater than 0
  summarise(Transactions = sum(Transactions > 0))

## # A tibble: 4 x 2
##   Factors Transactions
##     <chr>        <int>
## 1       a            2
## 2       b            1
## 3       c            1
## 4       d            0
```

---

You could also avoid `dplyr` by using `xtabs`, though some cleaning is necessary to get to the same arrangement:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% separate_rows(Factors) %>% 
  xtabs(Transactions > 0 ~ Factors, data = .) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  setNames(names(df))

##   Factors Transactions
## 1       a            2
## 2       b            1
## 3       c            1
## 4       d            0
```

---

A full base R equivalent:

```
df2 <- do.call(rbind, 
               Map(function(f, t){data.frame(Factors = strsplit(as.character(f), ',')[[1]], 
                                             Transactions = t)}, 
                   df$Factors, df$Transactions))

df3 <- as.data.frame(xtabs(Transactions > 0 ~ Factors, data = df2))
names(df3) <- names(df)

df3
##   Factors Transactions
## 1       a            2
## 2       b            1
## 3       c            1
## 4       d            0
```

Answer (score 3):

Equivalent `data.table` option:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, .(Factors = unlist(strsplit(as.character(Factors), ","))), 
      by = Transactions][,.(Transactions = sum(Transactions > 0)), by = Factors]

#   Factors Transactions
#1:       a            2
#2:       c            1
#3:       b            1
#4:       d            0
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a table using the unique values of the `Factor` column as the levels. Consider `df` to be your data set.

```
s <- strsplit(as.character(df$Factors), ",", fixed = TRUE)
table(factor(unlist(s[df$Transactions > 0]), levels = unique(unlist(s))))
#
# a c b d 
# 2 1 1 0
```

Wrap in `as.data.frame()` for data frame output.

```
with(df, {
    s <- strsplit(as.character(Factors), ",", fixed = TRUE)
    f <- factor(unlist(s[Transactions > 0]), levels = unique(unlist(s)))
    as.data.frame(table(Factors = f))
})
#   Factors Freq
# 1       a    2
# 2       c    1
# 3       b    1
# 4       d    0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` to split the 'Factors' into 'long' format and grouped by 'Factors' we get the `sum` of logical column ('Transactions > 0`).

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df1, "Factors", ",", "long")[, .(Transactions=sum(Transactions > 0)),.(Factors)]
#   Factors Transactions
#1:       a            2
#2:       c            1
#3:       b            1
#4:       d            0
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
with(df1, table(factor(unlist(strsplit(Factors[Transactions>0], ",")),
           levels = letters[1:4]) ))

#  a b c d 
#  2 1 1 0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Factors = c("a,c", "b", "c", "d,a", "a", "a", 
"b"), Transactions = c(2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("Factors", 
"Transactions"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```